# How to use the for loop in for loop in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to use the for loop in for loop (in postgreSQL) if i need parallel values for both the loops like (i,j) = (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)

I tried with this piece of code -

```
FOR i IN COALESCE(ARRAY_LOWER(ids, 1), 1) .. COALESCE(ARRAY_UPPER(ids, 1), 0)
LOOP
FOR j IN COALESCE(ARRAY_LOWER(cids, 1), 1) .. COALESCE(ARRAY_UPPER(cids, 1), 0)
LOOP
 --add the link between id and cids
INSERT INTO intervals (
                columns)
              VALUES (
                      --cid[j],
                      --id[i]
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. But if you simply wanted to insert the cartesian product of two one-dimensional array into your table, you just need a `CROSS JOIN`

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LalTYLB7)

```
INSERT INTO intervals (column_a, columnb)

SELECT 
    ids,
    cids
FROM unnest(ids) as ids            -- 1
CROSS JOIN unnest(cids) as cids
```

1. `unnest()` extracts the array elements into single rows.